# How to design a notification database schema in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, notifications

My application is about college search, there will be two kind of users, one the end users who search for colleges and other the college owners.

I am maintaining a common 'users' collection for both the kinds of users. Its schema looks like below

```
{
    _id : ObjectId(),
    display_name: String,
    email: String,
    password_hash: String,
    type :Number

}
```

Now an admin of this application wants to push a notification to the users, this notification may be for all the users or for a particular user or for the owners of the colleges or for a group of users.

A notification document consists of three things like below,

```
{
  _id : ObjectId(),
  notification_message: String,
  date: Date
}
```

Now what I want to do is to hit an api which gives me all the notifications of a particular user, along with a flag field for each notification which represents whether the notification is read or unread.

Now for this how should be my database design?

I thought of two options,

1. I want to maintain a notification collection and repeat the notification document for every intended user of the notification also I would maintain a field in this document as 'mark as read', the document will look like this

   ```
    {
      _id : ObjectId(),
     notification_message: String,
     date: Date,
     to_user_id : ObjectId(),
     mark_as_read: Boolean
     }
   ```

   **Pros**:Querying for the notifications of a particular user will be faster

   **Cons**:For each notification 'notification' collection will increase
             drastically as I am repeating the same notification in 
             notification collection for many users for whom the notification
            is intended to.

2.I want to maintain a notification collection and for each notification document I maintain an array of users for that notification and an array of users who have read this notification

**Pros:** Notification collection size may be less

**Cons:** Notification document may hit the maximum size of 16 MB

These are only two things I could think of, is there any other better way to do this? Your help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
{
    sender: Object, // user object
    receiver: [ String ] //array of user _ids
    message: String, // any description of the notification message 
    read_by: [{ readerId: String, read_at: Date }],
    created_at: Date,
}
```